# Adding data to the button and on click the data getting added to respective Excel Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to store a data/text on a button and while clicking the button the data should be added to respective excel cell. I tried all possible ways. I am getting the data on input box and from there on the cell. Below is the code

```
Sub OBS_Click()

iText = InputBox("test1")

Cells(iRow, 2).Value = iText

End Sub
```

Please let me know if it is possible to store value on a button and get the same value to a cell on click.

Regards

Ratish

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "store value on a button"  - do you mean the text on the button itself?

Comment: Hi SJR, sorry for that, yes text on the button.

Comment: Is this a button on a form or on a worksheet? If the latter is it an ActiveX or Forms button?

Comment: Basically, I need to add a text on the button and whenever I click that then the same text should come in the designated cell of a workbook.

Comment: The code depends on the type of button.

Comment: ActiveX button please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "OBS" is the button in question.

```
Sub OBS_Click()

Dim iText, iRow As Long, shp As Shape

iText = InputBox("test1")
iRow = 2
Cells(iRow, 2).Value = iText

ActiveSheet.Shapes("OBS").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption = iText

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR,
Thank you for the code, I am still getting input box which is not my requirement.

For eg: I want to add a button to my excel sheet and I want to add default email id on that button so whenever I click, A2 cell should automatically fill with those email id which is already stored or saved on the button through vba code.

Comment: Hi SJR,
I figured it.

Sub OBS()

Range("B2").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OBS"
    
End Sub

Comment: Eh? Why didn't you spell that out in your question?

Comment: really sorry, I just highlighted the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Sub OBS()

Range("B2").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OBS"

End Sub